# How to add iOS 10 default annotation/pin?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkmapview

I have a `MapView` in my app. And user can add an annotaion/pin to that `MapView`. I works fine but I would like to know if it is possible to add new annotation design.

This is the new pin:

[image]

This is what my map shows:

[image]

This is my annotation code:

```
let annotaion = MKPointAnnotation()
```

this line adds my annotation to map:

```
self.myMap.addAnnotation(self.annotaion)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is your deployment target is iOS 10?

Comment: Yep. But I started making this app in iOS 9

Answer (score 2):

I believe @0ndre_ was looking for the default image, not to bring in his own custom image. The answer by @Franco_Meloni was incomplete. Here is how I got it to work.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let pin = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        pin.canShowCallout = true

        let button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button

        if annotation.isEqual(mapView.userLocation) {
            return nil
        }
        return pin
    }
```

The key is using MKMarkerAnnotationView to get the bigger marker. If you use MKPinAnnotationView you will see the smaller one appear.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement

```
mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, 
              viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
```

from `MKMapViewDelegate` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview)

Implementation example:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let view = MKAnnotationView()
    view.image = UIImage(named: "pin")

    return view
}
```

Comment: When I use this:     func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let view = MKAnnotationView()
        view.image = UIImage(named: "pin") 
        
        return view
    }  it returns an empty map.. :/

Comment: is your image resource named "pin"?

Comment: No I Have not :/ . I do not know where is my image resource

Comment: If is in your bundle use let path = self.bundle.pathForResource("imageName", ofType: "jpg")

Comment: You have to create the image yourself in this case